# Navbar links that change .active as the page scrolls down

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a fixed navbar at the top of my page. I already have the jQuery which removes and adds the .active class as the links of the navbar are clicked and it scrolls to the right area. What I can't seem to find is, how do I have the same effect (the .active class is replaced) when the page is being scrolled down?

Comment: My issue is pretty clear. I will provide code as necessary. But the problem is not in the code, since I have no idea how to go about this.

Comment: I'm confused in how people don't think this is a clear question. It could use improvement sure, but you're asking about what sort of algorithm to use. That's... pretty easy to answer and see.

Comment: I kinda expect this from SO, unfortunately :( I think people just do it on purpose at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Scroll Event in Javascript

Thankfully this isn't to hard. You can use the [**scroll event**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll) in javascript to detect when the page is being scrolled.

## Using the Scroll Event Meaningfully

Now is the tricky part. You need to do some sort of detection to see what part of the page you're on, and then decide which links to add the class to(as a general rule each time you hit one of these points you should remove the class from the links in the first place).

Thankfully since this seems to be a vertical scroll, you should be able to do something along the lines of detecting what percentage of the page you've gone down to decide. Then as you hit those thresholds against a predicate you can do your logic there.

Comment: That's a great idea. Thank you, Robert. Im going to read up on scroll event. You mentioned % of the page scrolled down as one way, what about past a certain point of an id element?

Comment: Don't forget if this turns out the be the answer you were looking for to mark ti as the answer. If not, keep it open so someone else has a chance too!

Comment: Yeah I know. I am trying to figure it out with the link you provided

Comment: Certain point of an id element is a LOT harder to do which as so far I'm not certain people have found a really reliable way of doing...

Comment: Thank you. I'll attempt to create it with the % than.